# Angular2 http.post: Create promise with subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I´m trying do create a function, that returns a Promise as the code: (someprovider.ts)

```
postToPaymentApi(url:string, data:string, options:RequestOptions, order:Order):Promise<any>{
let result =  this.http.post(url, data, options).map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    // all my logic here!
    });
  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  })

  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    resolve(result)
  })
```

}

The problem is, when I call this function, I do not get the data, because this post take a few seconds to finish and I get the promise before the post finish.

```
this.postToPaymentApi(url, data, options, order).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't `.subscribe`, `.map` then convert it `.toPromise()`. Or just *use the observable*.

Comment: With .map and subscribe you are using Observable, it is a process asyncronous, you can use *ngIf for show the data in template

Answer (score 5):

if you want to create a function that return promise, your function should be :

```
postToPaymentApi(url:string, data:string, options:RequestOptions, order:Order):Promise<any >{
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.post(url, data, options)
           .map(res => res.json())
           .subscribe(data => {
             resolve(data);
            }
           }, error => {
             console.log(error)
             reject({error: error});
           });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Andre, you want to use the [`toPromise` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) to transform the observable returned by `.map()` into a promise. Return the result of that operator

```
return http.post(...).map(...).toPromise()
```

Now a proper promise is returned, so the calling code can use it as such:

```
postToPaymentApi(...).then(
    data => console.log(data)
)
```